# Does rendering on sheepit not render animations done using animation node?

Tags: rendering, animation-nodes, sheepit

I have this 1000 frames animation where I had the text animated using the animation nodes add-on. However, when I put it on sheepit, the online render farm, none of the text animations showed up. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: To render animation nodes you need to have it installed. If the render farm doesn't have it installed it will naturally not render

Comment: A render farm is a network of individual computers right? So in what sense must the render farm 'have it installed"? Please do excuse me if my question seems too naive.

Comment: Well that "network of computers" is composed of individual nodes that are going to have to open your file, read it, and render it. To accomplish those steps each and every single node of the netwrok must have all the required software to finish that task. That means having not only Blender installed, but also any "active" addons your file requires for interpretation, including Animation Nodes